# Identify EPSG code from image

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapping, epsg

We made a project where we asked students to draw things on a map. Now I would like to import the results into QGIS, but I am unable to find it. I used a picture but cannot find the name of the projection, the coordinates, a shapefile or anything...

Which EPSG code could be the right one?

[image]

Comment: It may not have an EPSG code

Comment: It appears to be a schematic figure of an Azimuthal equidistant projection ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection